# Correlation plot with one categorical variable and rest continuous

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, data-visualization, continuous-data

In my dataset, I have one binary variable (Active/Inactive) and rest of the variables are continuous. I have converted a categorical variable into binomial (0,1) and then ran a correlogram plot in R among each variable. Am I right in calculating a correlation value between categorical and continuous variables by simply using `corr_val <- cor(dataset)` and `corrplot(corr_val,type = "lower",order="hclust")`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As long as the categorical variable has been converted to binary form beforehand, than using the R `cor` with the Pearson default command will work, and the correlation will be a [point-biserial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient) correlation. Note that when transforming your categorical variable to a binary one you should use logical points (as it seems you have via active/inactive).

Answer (score 2):

In this way you lose the information related to the categorical variable.
You can try using the *featurePlot()* function from the *caret* package to display a scatterplot matrix.

```
library(caret)
featurePlot(x = dataset[, continuous variables], y = dataset[, categorical variable], plot = "pairs")
```